# ms sql insert into value from variable and select from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I want to insert into a table an value from variable and an select result.

```
declare @actual Date
set @actual = getdate()
```

---

This is my try:

```
insert into test (ID, Date) (select ID, @actual from Table)
```

---

I get an error Message!!

Comment: "An error message" - care to share? Those things *usually* include some useful information - even if *you* don't know what it means, it's possible that other people could help you. Also, when posting code, please highlight it and hit the `{}` button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `INSERT INTO..SELECT` statement,

```
DECLARE @actual Date
SET @actual = GETDATE()

INSERT INTO test (ID, Date) 
SELECT ID, @actual 
FROM   Tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try like this for using a select clause for Insert

insert into test(id,date) select col1,col2 from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TEST
(ID,DATE)
SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2 FROM TABLE
```